# Use type of object proprety as function parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm not quite sure how to explain this, and i've searched on TS docs and tried to find an example, but could not find any.

I have a configuration that specify operations to perform on an object property. And i want theses  function parameters to match the underling object prop type

I'm pretty sure there is a very clever way to do this.

Basically, Here is the problem I'm trying to solve:

```js
class Test {
  a = 1
  b = true
  c = 'asdf'
}


type ConfigFn<T , K> = (val : K) => void

// THIS IS ONLY AN EXAMPLE AND ITS NOT WORKING
type  Config<T>      = { [key : keyof T] : ConfigFn<T , typeof T[key]> }

const o : Config<Test> = {
  a : (val : number) => {
  },

  b : (val : boolean) => {
  },

  c : (val : string) => {
  },
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `type Config<T> = { [key in keyof T]: ConfigFn<T, T[key]> }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight modification to your code makes it work:

```
class Test {
    a = 1
    b = true
    c = 'asdf'
}

type ConfigFn<T> = (val: T) => void

type Config<T> = { [key in keyof T]: ConfigFn<T[key]> }

const o: Config<Test> = {
    a: (val) => { // type of val inferred as number
    },

    b: (val) => { // type of val inferred as boolean
    },

    c: (val) => { // type of val inferred as string
    },
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeBYAUNH0zQF5oBGLXaAI0OiQCcBXeM3YagckgBMAzNrAXyxYkATwAO8aAGEA9gDtuASwDmAMTkAeWAD5qACgBuYEAC44ASkK6DMxZyGZRE6fKXKtuoqmgBtANbwItCKctABIjLccAC6ZrIKKupa-oHRuoKYWMDyyNAyca4qWohInmjMOGBmhsaWBLreAPSNNOKSkdBGIMEK8LS08Jx4MHL0ALYUfRXQ-AA0DuQU1V11DdDNrc4dXT3cfQNDkJQyMiDwYHLTcwssy7VWaOstTu1ROyF7-YPD0Mi0IcorvNMBkgA)

Comment: AHH ! I was so close ! I did not know you could skip the `:` in `[key in keyof T]` Thanks !